# How do Toads in Naruto produce Oil?

Tags: naruto

Toad oil as shown on Mount Myoboku was produced from a special fountain that allowed user to more easily feel the natural energy around them. This was used in the initial stages of Senjutsu training by Jiraiya and Naruto.

However, We've seen several combo jutsu's used by Jiraiya which rely on the Toads spitting Oil (Toad Oil Bullet). Which can be lit on fire or even mixed with both Wind and Fire Jutsu. We know toads can manipulate Chakra and are mostly affiliated with Water Style.

So Is the toad oil produced naturally in the Toad's stomach's or is it something that they achieve by nature manipulation (manipulating multiple chakra natures, similar to Kekkei Genkai)?

**Update:** I understand "Toad Oil" based techniques utilize chakra, but the source of the oil is not explained. I have read the wiki entries and Wiki just states "converts Chakra to oil" but doesn't explain it. Is it like the Dragon Flame produced by Dragons? For an in universe example take a look at Katsuyu and her/its ability. I can see Slugs producing Slime and Katsuyu using that slime similar to that of the Mizukage's Acid Release. This is both a Nature transformation and Kekkei Genkai, while also possible naturally. **Do toads naturally produce this oil, do a nature transformation, Is there any myth that attributes toad spitting oil etc. is what my question moves toward.**

Additionally, for those confused about Ying-Yang techniques and Nature Transformations should go through the wikia page and read the cited information! [Naruto Wikia - nature Transformation](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_transformation)

> Aside from the five elemental nature transformations, there is a second kind of nature transformation that are the source of all non-elemental techniques such as the Shadow Imitation Technique, Multi-Size Technique, medical ninjutsu, genjutsu, etc. There is Yin Release (陰遁, Inton), based on the imagination and spiritual energy of a shinobi, and Yang Release (陽遁, Yōton), based on the vitality and physical energy of a shinobi. Together, they are used to perform Yin–Yang Release (陰陽遁, In'yōton, Onmyōton).

You can't just club any random technique to be Ying/Yang.

**Additional Update:** [Trivia section of Wikia for the Nature transformation](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_transformation#Trivia) gave an interesting lead.

> Techniques such as the *Toad Oil Bullet and the Poison Mist* mention "converting" or "kneading" chakra into materials or substances, *but have never been mentioned to use certain chakra natures.*

So I think I am not the only one unsure how these techniques are performed!

Comment: It's one of the toad's abilities. Jiraiya was not able to properly balance his own chakra with natural energy, resulting in his appearance taking on a number of toad-like traits when using Sage Mode including using oil-related techniques.

Answer (score 2):

The [Toad Oil Bullet](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Toad_Oil_Bullet) Is a skill used by Jiriya that converted his chakra into Toad oil. He spit out a volume of oil more than his body's size, proving that he could not have stored it inside his body. So the answer appears to be that there is a technique that converts chakra to Toad oil.

However, It is entirely possible the Toads, especially Larger ones, can swallow toad oil and regurgitate it later to conserve chakra usage required to create it.

It is notable that the Toad oil they spit out and Toad oil used in Senjutsu training might be different oils. The wiki entry on [Mount Myoboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku) notes:

> There is a sacred fountain on Mount Myōboku which produces a special oil which allows people to more easily feel the natural energy around them

So it seems only the fountan produces the Sage Mode oil. Also, the Sage Mode oil looks significantly like cooking oil, very light, clear, and of the same consistency, while The oil spit out to be ignited looks dirty, and dark, sometimes even opaque.

Edit: addressing your edit, There is only one thing that could possibly be added, and its a Theory.

You copied one line from the wiki on the trivia section of the [Nature Transformation](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation) page. However, the very next line gives off a HUGE hint.

> Certain other techniques involved in manipulating substances are also often confused to be chakra natures, such as silk, bone, and ink. However, these substances cannot be produced from chakra alone, meaning the chakra is not changed in nature, and it is rather used to change already-existing substances.

The oil is called Toad Oil, So its could be some kind of substance a Toad can naturally create. If that is the case, then this would literally be exactly like Kimimarus Bone based Jutsu, [Shikotsumaku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikotsumyaku), or [Kidomaru's Spider Technqiues](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kid%C5%8Dmaru). Just like how They can take the natural substance that already exists (bone/Spider Silk) and use Chakra to create more of it, Toads would do the same. Perhaps that is what Kneading into a substance means, Mixing Chakra with a substance, and converting the chakra into more of that substance. Since everyone who uses Toad Oil is either a Toad, or Jiriya after he goes Sage mode and becames part toad, then they would likely have a natural source of it to duplicate via Chakra kneading, if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Use this for future references : http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/formatting :)

Comment: *"Converted his Charka to Toad Oil"*, any other source for this wording other than the wikia? From what I have seen in the Anime/Manga, we have only five nature transformation and Oil wasn't one of them! Hence the question how is the Toad Oil produced. Also since the "Elder" Toads also use Oil based jutsus, the initial "Regurgation" theory seems false. IIRC filler chapters have Naruto learn such a technique by having Gamatatsu swallow a lot of water since he didn't know any water techniques, but this is never mentioned in canon.

Comment: @Arcane There is also both Yin and Yang release, as well as Yin-Yang (Yin-Yang is a legendary one, extremely rare), which address just about everything else, like genjutsu, Shadow Possession, Medical Ninjutsu, and such. If you also see when toad oil is used, its often far greater amounts than reasonable to be stored in something like a stomach outside of the Giant toads.

Comment: @Ryan I am not sure you understand the Nature Transformations. The Light and Dark(Yin-Yang) techniques don't change the chakra into any material. They use it to perform different tasks such as convert your Body/spirit to affect the real world (Mind, Shadow and Body for example for Ino-Shika-Cho). You can't just lump any random technique into Yin-Yang or Nature release. Updating the question.

Comment: @Arcane They basically do though. The Creation of all things Technique is a Yin-Yang for a reason, because, it does infact create things. Naruto used it to create a whole new eye for Kakashi. Elementally, Chakra is converted into Water, Fire, and Lightning, as well as Lava, and that is just the obvious ones where the material was not there before. If we can convert Chakra into those things, AND with enough skill into real working body parts, then making it into Oil is very possible. Since Oil is not a chakra nature, there is only Yin/Yang and Yin-Yang Left.

Comment: @Arcane Also, Edited my question to address your edit, Though, as you point out, It basically means there is no Canon Answer, just theories.